# Windowsサーバーにて、javaのcoredumpを意図的に出力したい

Tags: java, windows-server, logging

Windowsサーバーにて、Javaのコアダンプを意図的に出力したいと思いっています。
プロセスを強制終了しても出力されないので、出力方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃれば教えていただければ幸いです。

環境
Java(TM) SE Development Kit 11.0.12(64-bit)
WindowsServer 2019

Answer (score 1):

[JDKのドキュメント](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/troubleshoot/diagnostic-tools.html#GUID-C7CC8F8A-E763-4EE2-BC41-CA7E1086570B)には[userdumpコマンド](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/use-userdump-create-dump-file)の利用例がありました。

Answer (score 0):

「Javaのコアダンプ」とのことですが、Java のスレッドダンプでしょうか？

それであれば、まず **jps** でプロセスIDを特定します。

```
C:\> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12.7\bin\jps.exe"
17616 JShellToolProvider
17812 Jps
17816 RemoteExecutionControl
```

次に、そのプロセスIDを指定して **jstack** を実行します。

```
C:\> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12.7\bin\jstack.exe" 17616
2022-09-05 23:20:43
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (18.0.2+9 mixed mode, sharing):

Threads class SMR info:
_java_thread_list=0x000001b03aa6f0c0, length=20, elements={
0x000001b00f4869b0, 0x000001b00f54dc10, 0x000001b00f54ea70, 0x000001b0357a79a0,
0x000001b0357a8340, 0x000001b0357a8ce0, 0x000001b0357a9680, 0x000001b0357adad0,
0x000001b0357b8620, 0x000001b0357bb010, 0x000001b039c9c2d0, 0x000001b039d30460,
0x000001b039fea160, 0x000001b039ff0650, 0x000001b03a348110, 0x000001b03a37a600,
0x000001b03a464af0, 0x000001b03b8ec410, 0x000001b03b503fa0, 0x000001b03b504470
}

"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=1703.12ms elapsed=161.23s tid=0x000001b00f4869b0 nid=2568 in Object.wait()  [0x000000631f7fe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@18.0.2/Native Method)
        - waiting on <no object reference available>
        at jdk.internal.org.jline.utils.NonBlockingInputStreamImpl.read(jdk.internal.le@18.0.2/NonBlockingInputStreamImpl.java:139)
        - locked <0x00000006e02d91c0> (a jdk.internal.jshell.tool.ConsoleIOContext$1)
        at jdk.internal.org.jline.utils.NonBlockingInputStream.read(jdk.internal.le@18.0.2/NonBlockingInputStream.java:62)
        at jdk.internal.org.jline.utils.NonBlocking$NonBlockingInputStreamReader.read(jdk.internal.le@18.0.2/NonBlocking.java:168)
        at jdk.internal.org.jline.utils.NonBlockingReader.read(jdk.internal.le@18.0.2/NonBlockingReader.java:57)
        at jdk.internal.org.jline.keymap.BindingReader.readCharacter(jdk.internal.le@18.0.2/BindingReader.java:160)
        at jdk.internal.org.jline.keymap.BindingReader.readBinding(jdk.internal.le@18.0.2/BindingReader.java:110)
        at jdk.internal.org.jline.keymap.BindingReader.readBinding(jdk.internal.le@18.0.2/BindingReader.java:61)
        at jdk.internal.org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.doReadBinding(jdk.internal.le@18.0.2/LineReaderImpl.java:923)
        at jdk.internal.org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.readBinding(jdk.internal.le@18.0.2/LineReaderImpl.java:956)
        at jdk.internal.jshell.tool.ConsoleIOContext$2.readBinding(jdk.jshell@18.0.2/ConsoleIOContext.java:173)
        at jdk.internal.org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.readLine(jdk.internal.le@18.0.2/LineReaderImpl.java:651)
        at jdk.internal.org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.readLine(jdk.internal.le@18.0.2/LineReaderImpl.java:468)
        at jdk.internal.jshell.tool.ConsoleIOContext.readLine(jdk.jshell@18.0.2/ConsoleIOContext.java:249)
        at jdk.internal.jshell.tool.JShellTool.getInput(jdk.jshell@18.0.2/JShellTool.java:1281)
        at jdk.internal.jshell.tool.JShellTool.run(jdk.jshell@18.0.2/JShellTool.java:1215)
        at jdk.internal.jshell.tool.JShellTool.start(jdk.jshell@18.0.2/JShellTool.java:1001)
        at jdk.internal.jshell.tool.JShellToolBuilder.start(jdk.jshell@18.0.2/JShellToolBuilder.java:261)
        at jdk.internal.jshell.tool.JShellToolProvider.main(jdk.jshell@18.0.2/JShellToolProvider.java:120)

（略）
```